# Fill-in Missing Dates with calendar table

Tags: mysql

Hi i want the output to look like this. Filling the missing dates from the DATE_TBL. I tried UNION but no luck.

[image: Desired output]

From this table: Log_table:

[image: my table]

and DATE_TBL

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM DATE_TBL
LEFT JOIN LOG_TBL USING(date)
```